# Spring boot microservices and Docker, unable to connect to database

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I'm writing a test app in microservices to learn Spring Boot. I'm done with the app and looking to deploy it on AWS using docker/docker-compose to host each microservices.

I'm unable to connect any of the Spring Boot instances to their Mysql database. I've been stuck on it for a few days and I can't see what's wrong.

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3.3"
services:
  card_mysql:
    image: "mysql"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "root"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "cards"
    ports:
      - "33061:3306"

  auth_mysql:
    image: "mysql"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "root"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "auth"
    ports:
      - "33062:3306"

  market_mysql:
    image: "mysql"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "root"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "market"
    ports:
      - "33063:3306"

  user_mysql:
    image: "mysql"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "root"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "user"
    ports:
      - "33064:3306"

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8000:8080

  user:
    image: "openjdk:11"
    restart: always
    entrypoint: java -jar /app/services/user/target/cardmarket-user-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    depends_on:
      - "user_mysql"

  card:
    image: "openjdk:11"
    restart: always
    entrypoint: java -jar /app/services/card/target/cardmarket-card-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    depends_on:
      - "card_mysql"

  market:
    image: "openjdk:11"
    restart: always
    entrypoint: java -jar /app/services/market/target/cardmarket-market-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    volumes:
    - ./:/app
    depends_on:
      - "market_mysql"

  proxy:
    image: "openjdk:11"
    restart: always
    entrypoint: java -jar /app/zuul-proxy/target/zuul-proxy-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    volumes:
      - ./:/app

  auth:
    image: "openjdk:11"
    restart: always
    entrypoint: java -jar /app/zuul-proxy/zuul-proxy-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    depends_on:
      - "auth_mysql"
```

Here are each of my spring datasource settings:

user application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://user_mysql:3306/user
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
```

market application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://market_mysql:3306/market
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
```

Auth application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://auth_mysql:3306/auth
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
```

Card application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://card_mysql:3306/cards
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
```

I'm sure it is something small I'm missing or misunderstood, but I can't figure out what.

**Edit 1**

I ran a couple more tests but still wasn't able to figure out what's wrong.
I commented out everything but the card and card_mysql containers. The spring boot instance throw an exception for every configuration possible (using docker dns name, localhost, shared and network ip), none of them seems to work.
The two containers do communicate, I can ping between them using the dns name.

I'm using docker-desktop with wsl and deploy my containers on a wsl Ubuntu 20.04. I haven't tried on an actual Linux machine.

I've also tried to make the spring boot instance wait for the mysql one using [wait-for-it.sh](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it), it does wait correctly but the exception still occurs.

Here is parts of the exception spring boot triggers:

```
2021-05-16 12:23:48.948 INFO 1 --- [ main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-05-16 12:23:50.277 ERROR 1 --- [ main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
...
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
...
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

**Edit 2**
I tried having just one instance of spring boot and mysql and linking them using a network, unfortunately the exception still triggers. The two containers still pings. Here is the docker-compose I used for this test:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  card_mysql:
    image: "mysql"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "root"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "cards"
    networks:
      - "card_network"

  card:
    image: "openjdk:11"
    restart: always
    entrypoint: ["/app/wait-for-it.sh", "card_mysql:3306", "--", "java", "-jar", "/app/services/card/target/cardmarket-card-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
#    entrypoint: ["/app/wait-for-it.sh", "card_mysql:3306", "--", "ping", "card_mysql"]
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    depends_on:
      - "card_mysql"
    networks:
      - "card_network"
networks:
  card_network: {}
```

Comment: You are exposing port numbers 33061,33062, 33063, etc. for mysql. But, in spring properties file you are only using 3306. Change it appropriately for each service and give it a try.

Comment: @dossani the exposed ports only matter for things connecting to the host. For connections between containers, the port mapping doesn't matter. You would always use port 3306.

Comment: In what way is your code failing? There's an excellent chance that your application is starting up before MySQL is ready. `depends_on` is mostly useless, since that just waits for the *container* to start; Docker doesn't know anything about whether or not the application is ready. Your code should have retry logic for connecting to the database.

Comment: I've edited the post. The spring boot containers all have a restart option, is it not enough ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Spinarial please add **network** and gather it all in one network

```
          version: "3.4"

         services:
            springMvcRestApi:
                image: springbootproject:0.0.1
                container_name: app
                networks:
                   - postgres
                      ports:
                   -  8085:8085
                depends_on:
                   - postgres
                   - pgadmin
                links:
                   - postgres
                environment:
                   SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/reactiveDbcd?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
                   SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: postgres
                   SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: 12345

         postgres:
            container_name: postgres
            image: postgres
         environment:
            POSTGRES_USER: postgres
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 12345
            PGDATA: /data/postgres
         volumes:
           - postgres:/data/postgres
         expose:
           - 5432
         ports:
           - 5432:5432
         networks:
           - postgres
         restart: unless-stopped

       pgadmin:
         container_name: pgadmin_container
         image: dpage/pgadmin4
         environment:
              PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL:-pgadmin4@pgadmin.org}
              PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD:-admin}
              PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE: 'False'
         volumes:
          - pgadmin:/root/.pgadmin

         ports:
            - "${PGADMIN_PORT:-80}:80"
         networks:
            - postgres
         restart: unless-stopped

     networks:
       postgres:
          driver: bridge

     volumes:
        postgres:
          pgadmin:
```

Comment: Hello, I just edited the post. It doesn't seems to work either, I'm starting to think it must be a problem spring-boot side, like if spring-boot couldn't resolve the container name

Comment: If you want, I can share the sample that I wrote myself?